# Getting 404s for source maps of node modules while running angular 2 project

Tags: angular, http-status-code-404, systemjs, node-modules, source-maps

I have an angular 2 project, which, while running, gives a lot of 404s for source maps of various node modules as seen below:

```
...
[1] 16.07.28 07:53:19 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/abstract_form_group_directive.js.map
[1] 16.07.28 07:53:19 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/form_array_name.js.map
[1] 16.07.28 07:53:19 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/form_control_name.js.map
[1] 16.07.28 07:53:19 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/form_group_directive.js.map
[1] 16.07.28 07:53:19 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/form_group_name.js.map
[1] 16.07.28 07:53:19 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/form_control_directive.js.map
[1] 16.07.28 07:53:19 404 GET /node_modules/systemjs/dist/form_group_directive.js.map
...
```

I personally am not referencing them (at least not directly) in my code. When I searched for when they are, I found them almost always within their respective node modules.

For example:

`form_group_directive.js.map` is referenced in the last line of `form_group_directive.js` shown below:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=form_group_directive.js.map
```

`form_group_directive.js` itself is located under `node_modules/@angular/forms/src/directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive.js`

Looking further into my code to identify how `form_group_directive.js.map` may be referenced, I find the following:

In one of my components, I have imported `REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES` as follows:

```
import {
FORM_DIRECTIVES, FORM_PROVIDERS, FormGroup, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES,
FormControl, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
...
@Component({
    selector: "search-form",
    templateUrl: "app/search-form.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["app/search-form.component.css"],
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [FORM_PROVIDERS]
})
```

In the component template, I use the `formGroup` directive as follows:

```
...
<form id="search-criteria" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)">
....
```

Tracing `REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES` in `@angular/forms` leads the file `directives.d.ts` under `node_modules/@angular/forms/src/directives.d.ts`, which has this line:

```
...
export { FormGroupDirective } from './directives/reactive_directives/form_group_directive';
...
```

So, the js file path seems to get correctly resolved. However, source map file it points does not.

It seems like they are being searched for in the wrong place. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Please post the records at which you are referencing those files.

Comment: I personally am not referencing them in my code. When I searched for when they are, I found them almost always within their respective node modules . For example:  `ng_model_group.js.map` is referenced in the last line of `ng_model_group.js` as `//# sourceMappingURL=ng_model_group.js.map` under `node_modules > @angular > forms > esm > src > directives`

Comment: But.. is the path to the files correct? I mean, if you enter the command `cat /node_modules/systemjs/dist/ng_model_group.js.map` do you see the contents of the file?

Comment: I'm asking this because the error shows ABSOLUTE file location...

Comment: The source map files are located in the same directory as their js files (i.e. within some node_module. However, for some reason they are searched for under `systemjs>dist`. So following on the example in my previous comment, the correct location of the source file is `node_modules\@angular\forms\esm\src\directives\ng_model_group.js.map`

Comment: OK, this matches my hunch. You have an error in the way these files are references in the first place. Without seeing your code, there is no much help that can be given.

Comment: @FDavidov , I've edited the question to point that out

Comment: It would appear that the way they are referenced is not **relative** (I would expect a `#` sign somewhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few bugs:

> the templateUrl is loaded relative to the root of the dev server instead of relative to the package.

Use require as a workaround for templates with non-static assets:

```
template: require('app/search-form.component.html')
```

> some of the components have static assets which get served from the root and not relative to the package (node_modules/package_path/path/to/assets) nor does the bundler pick it up.
>
> Basically, there's no decent way to bundle 3rd party libs that do not inline their html/css. At the moment we use some regex to figure it out for ts files, but it's somewhat risky... it might replace stuff it shouldn't.
>
> It looks like changes in TS2.0+ prevent a relative sourceMapUrl from being generated despite the adding the mapRoot attribute in the tsconfig.json

**References**

- [Angular2 Issue #10614: Component relative paths are not being respected](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10614)
- [Angular2 Issue #1624: Webpack build breaks ability to use npm installed custom components](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1624)
- [TypeScript Issue #10612: Not producing relative sourceMappingUrl's with mapRoot](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10612)
- [Webpack Issue #2995: /* #sourceMappingURL= ... */" in a JS comment triggers a webpack errors](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2995)
- [Babel Issue #3751: impossible to pass inline sourcemaps from typescript through es6 > es5 transpilation ("Invalid mapping" error) (T6686)](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/3751)
- [Babel Issue #6060: babel-register does not load external source maps](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/6060)
- [systemJS Issue #450: In-browser transpilation sourcemaps do not work outside of Chrome](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/450)